# IE 10-11 Dropdown Menu Issues Using Up/Down Keys

Tags: internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I am having an issue with IE 10-11 dropdown menus. When click on the drop down menu and use either up or down keys for selecting items from the menu, it highlights everything in the menu. Normal behavior is that only one selection is highlighted. When everything is highlighted, it makes it hard for users to see what selection they have made.

Anyone know what is going on here? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but it's just simple HTML: `<select>
<option>Test 1</option>
<option>Test 2</option>
<option>Test 3</option>
<option>Test 4</option>
<option>Test 5</option>
</select>
`
'

Comment: I don't see the same results: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/jonb2j3b/